# Beamer - Textblock and Show notes on second screen

Tags: beamer, positioning, notes

my question might seem to have been already asked in [Absolute positioning in beamer when using `show notes on second screen`: text on wrong page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89539/absolute-positioning-in-beamer-when-using-show-notes-on-second-screen-text-on) or in [Title picture misplaced in Beamer when using 'show notes on second screen' and absolute 'pgf' positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/title-picture-misplaced-in-beamer-when-using-show-notes-on-second-screen-and-a) but although those topics have been solved, the corresponding solutions do not match my problem.

My idea is simple : I would like to use beamer's dual screen mode while using textblocks with absolute positioning in my presentation, so that I can place the figures where I want.

Here is a simple code, which is inspired by this topic : [Title picture misplaced in Beamer when using 'show notes on second screen' and absolute 'pgf' positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/title-picture-misplaced-in-beamer-when-using-show-notes-on-second-screen-and-a).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86378/86}
\usepackage{pgfpages,tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes,overlay]{textpos}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}\nofiles

\author{Euclid}
\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, shift={(5mm,5mm)}]
   at (current page.south west)
   [fill=red!20,rounded corners, above right]
   {\Huge\LaTeX};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock}{65}[0,0](20,20)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, shift={(5mm,5mm)}]
    at (current page)
    [fill=red!20,rounded corners, above right]
    {\Huge\LaTeX};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If one uncomments the `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}\nofiles`, one can see that the solution suggested in the previous topic works for the titlegraphic, but not for the textblocks : those are sent to the previous slide and on the right screen (in the presentation if the notes are displayed on the left screen, and in the notes if they are displayed on the right screen).

Everywhere I have been seeking on the internet, it seems that these two options (`textpos` with absolute positionning and `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`) are incompatible, put I am still hoping someone would have found a solution. 
Does anybody actually have ?

Comment: The issue is assumably the interference of `pgfpages` and `textpos` at the shipout level, which is the reason I have totally stopped using `pgfpages`, but use tools like `pdfjam` for post-processing the resulting PDF. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53560/3751 for an example. However, Andrew Stacey found a [workaround](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53606/3751) for the interference issue. I have never tried it, but it may work in your case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a `tikzpicture` with the `remember picture, overlay` options. This allows you to absolutely position the image on the page without the need to fiddle with `textpos`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86378/86}
\usepackage{pgfpages,tikz}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\author{Euclid}
\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, shift={(5mm,5mm)}]
   at (current page.south west)
   [fill=red!20,rounded corners, above right]
   {\Huge\LaTeX};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (5.9,-0.5) [fill=red!20,rounded corners, above right]
    {\Huge\LaTeX};
  \end{tikzpicture}%  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]