# Image centered on full slide with background color in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, backgrounds

Specifying both a background color and a background image for beamer slides is a bit tricky when notes are shown. I tried three approaches but none works perfectly (the idea is to avoid white borders above and below a full-screen image).

The first solution was inspired by this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26459) :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name}
  }
}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

But setting the background color has no effect. I also tried to include the graphics inside the frame but the image is not centered anymore :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name}
}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

My last test is based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3927) :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}\nofiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[at=(current page.center)] {
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\note{Note}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

But the image is not positioned correctly when notes are shown (even with the [nofiles trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86673/38915)).

Each solution has a distinct problem. Any idea on one possible fix?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try my best to stick to it. I was actually wondering whether I should present all my investigations in the question (it makes the question unnecessary long and it can even be seen at three separate questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `background canvas` is defined as

```
\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{default}
{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\vrule width\paperwidth height\paperheight}%
}
```

So it just draws a box filling the whole frame with the `background canvas` color. That's why changing the background canvas color does not have any effect anymore, if the default `background canvas` is overwritten.

But there is another background layer simply called `background` which is drawn on top of the `background canvas`. After changing `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}` to `\setbeamertemplate{background}` the first solution works.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{%
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name}
  }
}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

The second solution doesn't work because every beamer frame has a `text margin left` (and `text margin right`) and this shifts the image in this case to the right because with its width of `\paperwidth` it doesn't fit inside anymore. To solve the issue here one could shift it back using `\hspace` with a negative length. In this case it is `\hspace*{-1cm}`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\hspace*{-1cm}%
\parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name}
}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The proposed fix to the first solution works and the third solution mentioned in the question also works now.