# Absolute positioning of Tikz pictures on Beamer slides when using "show notes" option

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, pgf-core

TiKz allows you to position `tikzpicture`s anywhere on the page using the pre-defined `current page` co-ordinate.

However, when you also use Beamer's `show notes` option, which uses `pgfpages`, this destroys the absolute co-ordinate system.

I thought I had found a solution (see [Title picture misplaced in Beamer when using 'show notes on second screen' and absolute 'pgf' positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86378)). This uses the `\nofiles` command so that on a second LaTeX run, we retain the original AUX file (and the stored position of the `tikzpicture` using the `remember picture` option).

However, this only seems to work for the first occurrence of a slide with `tikzpicture`s. All subsequent slides still have the absolute positioning messed up.

Without the `\nofiles` command the `tikzpicture` size and position are wrong. Using the two-step compilation (`hide notes` followed by `show notes` with `\nofiles` command) the sizes are right, the position of the pictures on the first slide are right, all other positions are wrong.

I feel so close to understanding what is wrong/needs changing/how to fix this.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

%%%%% pick one of the following three lines:
%\setbeameroption{show only notes} 

%\setbeameroption{show notes}\nofiles

\setbeameroption{hide notes}

%% For the notes slides to work, we need to compile with 'hide notes' first,
%% this gets the position of all the tikz environments right. Then,
%% and only then, compile with the 'show notes' line, including the
%% \nofiles option. That will get the notes slides done properly.
%% [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/title-picture-misplaced-in-beamer-when-using-show-notes-on-second-screen-and-a]
%%

\usetheme{Frankfurt} %% header, filled blocks, toc(line)

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% the following puts a \notes{} command on every slide
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
  \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
  \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally empty.
}
\makeatother


\title{TEST}
\author{Someone}

\begin{document}

\section{SECTION}

\subsection{CONTENT}


\begin{frame}[fragile,label=pic1]{Title}{subtitle}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC1a) at ($(current page.south west)+(5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south west,draw=red] {PIC1a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC1b) at ($(current page.south east)+(-5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south east,draw=red] {PIC1b};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \note{Simple note\\\alert{First slide}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,label=pic2]{Title}{subtitle}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC2a) at ($(current page.south west)+(5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south west,draw=red] {PIC2a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC2b) at ($(current page.south east)+(-5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south east,draw=red] {PIC2b};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  %% NO EXPLICIT \note
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,label=pic3]{Title}{subtitle}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC3a) at ($(current page.south west)+(5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south west,draw=red] {PIC3a};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (PIC3b) at ($(current page.south east)+(-5mm,5mm)$) [anchor=south east,draw=red] {PIC3b};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \note{Simple note\\\alert{Third slide}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Below are the resulting PDFs (stacked with `pdfnup` and converted to PNGs for uploading) under:

1. Compiled with `hide notes` option
2. Compiled with `show notes` option and `\nofiles` after (1)
3. Compiled with `show notes` option, as a single pass without using `\nofiles`

[image: Minimal example with hide notes]
[image: Minimal example, second compilation with show notes]
[image: Very wrong, minimal example one-step compilation with show notes and not using nofiles command]

In the AUX file I see lines including `\pgfsyspdfmark`, which on reading *[114.15 Position Tracking Commands](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=1111)* from the pgfmanual (v3.0.1a), appear to be the lines of interest.

I just don't understand why the first slide is fine, with the `\nofiles` fix, but the subsequent slides are wrong. Am I missing something?

**Solution**

Make sure you have up to date packages. After doing an upgrade:

- beamer 2015/01/05 3.36
- pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- compiling with TeX Live 2013/Debian (on Ubuntu)

Using method (4), `show notes` option without any need for `\nofiles` works fine.

I have no idea what was changed in the upgrade... the above question came from using pgf v2.10.

Comment: One cannot determine the absolute location of anything on the page until the page ships, so each tikzpciture stores its origin location on the aux file.  So it cannot position things relative to (current page) until the aux file is read.

Comment: i see no problem with \setbeameroption{show notes}.  You just have to run it twice (SOP).

Comment: I would go with method `4. Compiled with show notes option, as many passes as necessary and without using \nofiles`

Comment: @JohnKormylo, when you say you see no problem... if you go with the two-step approach (compile with ``hide notes`` option followed by compile with ``show notes`` option and ``\nofiles`` command) do the TiKz nodes all  appear in the right place?

As shown in my second attached image, when I do this the second and third slides have the wrong position (but the correct size). I did perform multiple compilation passes in both steps - it seemed to make no difference.

Comment: @samcarter, could you attached an image of what your method (4) output looks like. When I try this approach, I get the output shown in my third image - the size and location of the TiKz nodes are wrong.

Comment: @Simon Sure, I get the following output http://i.stack.imgur.com/0rvvB.png Is this what you expect? I am using TeXLive 2016 with pdflatex (3 times). How are you compiling?

Comment: @samcarter, ah.

I just noticed I was using TiKz 2.10... just done an update and tried method (4). Everything seems fine.

Well that's embarrassing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tikz update solved the problem

Comment: @Simon Don't worry, if such things would not happen, there would be no questions to answer on this site :) Glad we could help you!